# How to understand first step of Newton's Method

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm studying a tutorial of using Newton's Method to approximate a value. The examples are given in terms of $a$. While I understand the gist of using Newton's Method to recursively update the value, I don't understand the first step in the tutorial in which the instructor redefines the value as a function in terms of $x$ and $a$.

**Example 1:**

Estimate $\frac{1}{a}$

Function used: $f(x) = a - \frac{1}{x}$

**Example 2:**

Estimate $\sqrt[3]{a}$

Function used: $f(x) = x^{3} - a$

How are the two functions in terms of $x$ and $a$ derived from the initial values in terms of $a$ only?

Comment: What happens if you solve each of those equations for $x$ from $f(x) = 0$? We just need to choose **any**  well behaved function that provides an iteration to the result we want.